# Customize woocommerce order tracking page

Tags: woocommerce

in the default order tracking page for wooocommerce there are two fields { ordreid and email }
.
I want to make email field unrequired 
I tried with this code in function.php file but it wasn't successful :(

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce-order-tracking', 'ts_unrequire_wc_email_field');
function ts_unrequire_wc_email_field( $fields ) {
$fields['order_email']['required'] = false;
return $fields;
}
```

any help will be useful .. and i hope that you are all safe during the breakout of covid-19 <3**

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i wish if you have time to take a look at this